# Couch DB + Pouch DB lazy loading list item possible or not?

Tags: arraylist, couchdb, lazy-loading, pouchdb

I am using pouchDB and CouchDB I have 10K records/Document in my database, at a time 10,000 records load in list its take long time to load in list, so now I want 20 - 20 records/Document load in my list.

Is it possible ?
if yes then how ?

thanks.

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried? Show us your code. What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are retrieving all docs in PouchDB check [allDocs API](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch)

You should use the following options for paginating the document retrieval

- *options.limit*: Maximum number of documents to return.
- *options.skip*: Number of docs to skip before returning (warning: poor performance on IndexedDB/LevelDB!).

  CouchDB has similar options for [bulk retrieval](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/bulk-api.html)